# User can only call methods if the object belongs the user

Tags: java, jsf, acl

In a CRUD jsf application, owners have objects, like records.

I want that owners can only view/edit/delete objects created by themselves. One way to achieve this, in every method to check if object has been created by the logged user.

There can be many similar methods and objects, so I would like to use another elegant/automatic way instead of using

```
if (selectedObject.owner == loggedUser)
```

phrases in every methods.

Is it possible,if possible how?

Comment: This looks like a elegant solution to me. The only thing that you can add is a bit of an abstraction, but I am not going to go through that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for access protection.

I'd write an aspect to intercept all method calls to the access restricted methods, apply the check in a *before* advice and throw an exception if it fails. Depending on the structure of the program either by looking for an explicit annotation or by using a rather generic pointcut.

This would move your `if (obj.owner.equals(loggedUser))` to one central place, but of course you'd still need to take care not to include other users' items in lists etc.

"The" Java aspect implementation is [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). It is also used and supported by the Spring framework, which you may already use anyway: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would *show* the component only if the user is authorized, by using

```
rendered={user.isOwner}
```

You will use this as an attribute in your component.

Comment: I dont want to use rendered attribute due to security issues. Because everyone can tamper posted data, change and repost again. It is a security flaw. It dosent prevent that methods to be called.